# QGIS identify each layer type in legend i.e point polygon line

Tags: qgis

i am developing a qgis plugin, while i can get the the general type of layer i.e vector or raster using this code

```
    vectorCount =0
pointCount=0
lineCount=0
polugonCount=0
rasterCount=0
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "count %i"%(vectorCount) )
        vectorCount=vectorCount+1
    if layer.geometryType() == Qgis.Point:
        QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "count %i"%(pointCount) )
        pointCount=pointCount+1
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

how i can get more specific vector layer type such as point polygon line ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how i can get more specific vector layer type such as point polygon line ? basically i want to develop a plug in that will automatically arrange the layers in proper order: at base polygon then line then point. i am also wondering to use  their extent or area of extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if layer.geometryType() == Qgis.Point:
        print "I'm a point layer"
```

http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a0c6711ef5b047f27f99c4463d5390e59

Comment: if layer.geometryType() == qgis.point                 NameError: global name 'qgis' is not defined

Comment: @Nathan W said - `if layer.geometryType() == Qgis.Point:
        print "I'm a point layer"` you need a capital Q on the Qgis qualifier in the statement, I think. Your's appears to be `if layer.geometryType() == qgis.point` (nb qgis instead of Qgis)

Comment: Not working         vectorCount =0
 pointCount=0
 lineCount=0
 polugonCount=0
 rasterCount=0
 layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
 for layer in layers:
  if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
   QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "count %i"%(vectorCount) )
   vectorCount=vectorCount+1
  if layer.geometryType() == Qgis.Point:
   QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "count %i"%(pointCount) )
   pointCount=pointCount+1
 self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

Comment: i tried self.iface, Qgis.GeometryType.Point  tried almost all the thing ...

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks nathan w and mark your answers gave me direction. actually 'G' in Qgis.Point:has to be capital , this is how got it to run:

```
    vectorCount =0
pointCount=0
lineCount=0
polygonCount=0
rasterCount=0
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        vectorCount=vectorCount+1
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
        pointCount=pointCount+1
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line:
        lineCount=lineCount+1
    if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon:
        polygonCount=polygonCount+1
```